# Can't we stop the time?

Tags: temperature, time, matter, states-of-matter, low-temperature-physics

Time is called as a measurement of difference between two or more incidents. So if we stop happening incidents can't we stop the TIME? Eventhough it's impractical, I mean if we reduce the temperature of earth to absolute zero.... isn't it stop the motion of matter and stop the time? When we start increasing temperature again isn't the time starts from where we stopped?

Comment: It's something came to my mind recently

Answer (score 0):

Even if you stop the time, quantum mechanically, the energies of systems are not zero. The simplest example would be quantum harmonic oscillator which has a ground state at $E_0=\hbar\omega/2$.

In any case, Heisenberg's uncertainty principle also prohibits to completely stop the movement of a particle as that would mean we have absolutely no idea where that particle is in the entire universe.

Answer (score 0):

According to the special relativity, if you are able to move close to the speed of light then time might be slow down because in your frame of reference the speed of light also be speed of light we can not allow the relative velocity. The event horizon of a black hole is one of the closest place for almost completely stop of time...